# How do I store an array of objects that have arrays as value in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

How do I store an array of objects that have arrays as value in Redux where the value is an array of items and key is a string like the name. I have to store something like:

```
[{
    name: 'ron',
    team: ['josh','brian'],
  },
{
   name: 'marie',
  team: ['ann', 'kevin']

    }
]
```

This is the code I have with just the name:

```
import {v4 as uuid} from 'uuid';
const initalState = [
  {
    id: uuid(),
    name: ''
  }
];


const trainerReducer = (state = initalState, action) => {
  const {type, payload} = action;

  switch (type) {
    case 'CREATE_TRAINER':
      console.log('payload', payload);
      return [...state, {id: uuid(), name: payload.name}];
   

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default trainerReducer;
```

Also, any documentation on how to add,update, delete this in redux would be appreciated.

Comment: What is wrong with the above code? 
What are you expecting?

Comment: How do I add an array to it? something like team = []. I don't know how to append this in redux.

Comment: Do you want to add value to the team?

Comment: Yes, to the teams array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the team when you create a trainer.

```
const trainerReducer = (state = initalState, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case "CREATE_TRAINER":
      console.log("payload", payload);
      return [
        ...state,
        { id: uuid(), name: payload.name, team: payload.team ?? [] },
      ];

    case "ADD_TEAM":
      return state.map((trainer) =>
        trainer.id === payload.id ? { ...trainer, ...payload.team } : trainer
      );

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try this please :
create var or const array.

```
const arrayData = [{
    name: 'ron',
    team: ['josh','brian'],
  },
{
   name: 'marie',
  team: ['ann', 'kevin']

    }
];
```

then send this array to related method over action.

```
    import {v4 as uuid} from 'uuid';
    const initalState = [
      {
        id: uuid(),
        name: ''
      }
    ];
    
    
    const trainerReducer = (state = initalState, action) => {
      const {type, payload} = action;
      const arrayData = payload.arrayData;

      switch (type) {
        case 'CREATE_TRAINER':
          console.log('payload', payload);
          return [...state,[...arrayData], {id: uuid(), name: payload.name}];
       
...
...
...
```